# SQL Views "WITH CASCADE CHECK OPTION" Behaivor?

Tags: sql, view

I can't find any reference, or documentation on this.

```
CREATE VIEW view1 AS SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE x = 1;

CREATE VIEW view2 AS SELECT * FROM view1 WHERE y = 1 WITH CASCADE CHECK OPTION;
```

Does the condition clause read `x = 1 AND y = 1` in case of `UPDATE`/`INSERT` on view2?

Comment: Have you tested this in any way?

Comment: i can't :/ just got a truth table, that is either faulty or doesn't make any sense to me if it isn't that way.

Comment: this is just about the specification.. sql-92 in this case.. its more for better understanding then solving an actual problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so maybe have a look at

[WITH CASCADED CHECK OPTION](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=view-cascaded-check-option) and it's [example](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/i/7.3?topic=view-example-cascaded-check-option)

and

[Defining Views](https://docs.intersystems.com/ens20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GSQL_views)

It would seem that the `WITH CASCADE` option does enforce all view criteria.

Answer (score 1):

The option "With Cascade Check Option" is normally used with "Updatable Views". The given clause is used to prevent inserts or updates to rows except those for which the WHERE clause in the select_statement is true.